# Use external translation and configuration files with Jhipster

Tags: webpack, jhipster, ngx-translate

I need to use external translation files and configuration files with Jhipster frontend. So they won't be bundled with the build, and the values in the file can be changed easily. Any leads?

Comment: Have you considered getting rid of MergeJsonWebpackPlugin and then serving i18n json files from another server? Maybe using nginx as a reverse proxy if you don't want to change the URLs.

Comment: will try that. actually i am not much familiar with webpack :) Thanks